# Expo Camera zoomed video record

Tags: react-native, opengl-es, expo

I'm using Expo Camera on my android phone, and the record that gives me back is zoomed and while taking the picture or video, the camera view seems to be distorted. how can I set it to false, I tried to use react-native-camera instead but it crashes.

```
<Camera useCamera2Api={false} 
  ref={(el) => this.camera = el } 
  style={{ flex: 1, 
          flexDirection: 'column', 
          justifyContent: 'space-between', 
          alignItems: 'flex-start' }} 
          flashMode={this.state.flashmode ? Camera.Constants.FlashMode.on : Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
          type={this.state.type} 
          useNativeZoom={true}  
          defaultVideoQuality={Camera.Constants.VideoQuality['1080p']} 
          ratio={'16:9'} 
          autoFocus={Camera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}>
</Camera>
```

I render the video using react-native-video:

```
<Video  source={{ uri: this.state.preview }}
        style={{ flex: 1,  
        width:Dimensions.get('screen').width,
        height:Dimensions.get('screen').height, 
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', zIndex: 0 }} />
```

my react native version is 0.63.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called "resizeMode" in the Video component . Try with setting this prop to "cover" like this:

```
 <Video  source={{ uri: this.state.preview }}
    style={{ flex: 1,  
    width:Dimensions.get('screen').width,
    height:Dimensions.get('screen').height, 
    resizeMode={"cover"}
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', zIndex: 0 }} />
```